# How to check date day is between two given days

Tags: c#, datetime, date-comparison

I have to check that my specific date day is between two string days or equals to them
For instance:

```
var startDay = "Saturday";
var endDay = "Tuesday";
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;
if(myDate.DayofWeek >= startDay && myDate.DayofWeek <= endDay){
//some code here...
}
```

Comment: Duplicate, really? That one is about converting a string into the Enum which is certainly one thing OP needs to do, but the question here is about figuring out if a date is between two weekdays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse those strings to a `DayOfWeek` enum:

```
var startDay = "Saturday";
var endDay = "Tuesday";
DayOfWeek startDayOfWeek, endDayOfWeek;
if (!Enum.TryParse(startDay, out startDayOfWeek))
   // error handlnig
if (!Enum.TryParse(endDay, out endDayOfWeek))
   // error handlnig
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Now;
if(myDate.DayofWeek >= startDayOfWeek && myDate.DayofWeek <= endDayOfWeek){
    //some code here...
}
```

But that gives another problem: the values of `DayOfWeek` go from sunday (0) to saturday (6). And depending on what you define as start of your week or what *between* means, you might need to adjust the values.

So here is a suggestion:

```
int startDayAsInt = (int)startDayOfWeek; // the parsed value from above
int endDayAsInt = (int)endDayOfWeek;
int myDateAsInt = (int)myDate.DayOfWeek;

if (endDayAsInt < startDayAsInt) endDayAsInt += 7;
if (myDateAsInt < startDayAsInt) myDateAsInt += 7;
if (myDateAsInt >= startDayAsInt && myDateAsInt <= endDayAsInt)
    // do something
```

This should work for all combinations as it projects days into the "next" week if they are before the start day.

Comment: Vogt Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `DayOfWeek` enum.

```
if(myDate.DayOfWeek >= DayOfWeek.Tuesday 
   && myDate.DayOfWeek <= DayOfWeek.Saturday)
{
    // This would catch the days from Tuesday to Saturday
}
```

If you want to catch the days from Saturday to Tuesday you have to change a bit your code.

```
    if(myDate.DayOfWeek >= DayOfWeek.Saturday 
    || myDate.DayOfWeek <= DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
{
    // This would catch the days from Tuesday to Saturday
}
```

If your `startDate` and `endDate` are changing. Then you need to parse the first and do a few extra checks.

```
DayOfWeek startDayOfWeek;
DayOfWeek endDayOfWeek;
if (!Enum.TryParse(startDay, out startDayOfWeek))
{
    // Something wrong happened and you have to handle it.
}
if (!Enum.TryParse(endDay, out endDayOfWeek))
{
    // Something wrong happened and you have to handle it.
}
if (
       ((int)startDayOfWeek < (int)endDayOfWeek
         && myDate.DayOfWeek >= startDayOfWeek
         && myDate.DayOfWeek <= endDayOfWeek)
    || ((int)startDayOfWeek > (int)endDayOfWeek
         && (myDate.DayOfWeek >= startDayOfWeek
             || myDate.DayOfWeek <= endDayOfWeek))
   )
{

}
```

Comment: Wasn't the answer OP is looking for is the day between Saturday and Tuesday? This one is between Tuesday and Saturday which is the exact opposite.

Comment: Two days that i have mentioned in my question are dynamic they could be changed any time so in this scenario your solution won't work.

Comment: @juunas you are correct :) I Corrected my answer.

Comment: @Slan now it works dynamically.

Comment: @Christos Thank you so much